# C# - webclient decode the brackets on URL encoded string

Tags: c#, webclient, urlencode

I've got S3 presigned url with **Korean characters and brackets**

**URL sample** - https://*********.cloudfront.net/amazon_genesis.dev/be-storage-b76b4dd64-x66d7/0e05e8cf-9ecc-459c-aa90-3e4beddc2c9f/ecbc1896-a5da-4857-983f-6eb3f7bf0ee2/%EC%A0%84%EC%8B%9C%EC%9A%A9+%EB%B6%80%EC%B1%84+%EB%8D%B0%EC%9D%B4%ED%83%80%28%EC%88%98%EC%A0%95%29_%EC%9B%90%EB%B3%B8.hpd

When I paste that URL to the browser, the file is downloading.

But if I'm trying to download it with **.net 4.5 Webclient**, its fails.
In Fiddler the requested URL is the same except the brackets.
instead of Urlencoded presentation for the brackets (%28, %29), I saw that only the brackets were decoded to regular characters.
because of that the signed URL breaks.

The issue occurs only with **Asian languages and brackets**,
for strings without brackets or English with brackets all good.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Still didnt found solution, can anyone help?

Comment: No, I've changed all the file names to UUIDs and sends the real file names separately.